# Change Bash's Prompt Based on The User Using a Singe RC File

Tags: bash

## The Goal

A similar question has been asked many times but I haven't seen it implemented in a way that I want it to. I want to achieve the following:

- Set Bash's prompt to `username@hostname directory #` if it's root's session or `username@hostname directory $` for any other user.
- Define `.bashrc` file for my user only, and create a **symbolic link** to it for the root user (or any other user in general). I want to do this so that I don't have to copy a file for multiple users and keep the copies synchronized every time I update my `.bashrc`.

## What I Have So Far

```
# Bash prompt to ``username@hostname directory $ '' in bold
if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then
    PS1="\e[1m\u@\h \w # \e[0m"
else
    PS1="\e[1m\u@\h \w $ \e[0m"
fi
```

This, kind of works. If I launch the terminal in the session of my user, my prompt will be as expected. However, the issue arises when I use `su -` to switch to `root`'s session.

For some reason, the `.bashrc` does not get sourced, and I am stuck with the default prompt (`[root@hostname directory]#`). If I am to `source .bashrc`, the prompt will update to what I want it to be (`root@hostname directory #`).

## The Question

How can I achieve the result I want? One `.bashrc` file, symlinked for all other users, and properly loaded when I switch to any particular user.

Comment: IIRC, `su -` runs a login shell, and Bash doesn't read `.bashrc` from login shells. Unless you explicitly source it from `.profile`, or `.bash_profile`, or `.bash_login`, which ever one you have. So you may want to check that.

Comment: Thank you @ilkkachu

Comment: Also, using `\$` in the prompt should allow you to get rid of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

## The Solution

As [@ilkkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170373/ilkkachu) explained in the comments (a big "thank you" by the way):

> `su -` runs a login shell, and Bash doesn't read `.bashrc` from login shells. Unless you explicitly source it from `.profile`, or `.bash_profile`, or `.bash_login`, which ever one you have. So you may want to check that.

Hence, adding `source .bashrc` to my user's `.bash_profile`, and then creating a symbolic link to that `.bash_profile` for the root user worked.